# nodejs with Graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I am facing an issue, while trying graphQL. I guess I am doing something wrong at schema or resolver. Everything according to docs but still not able to get the data.

What Do I need is very simple user model to run its queries in graphiql.

Here is my code: [Download code (zip file)](https://app.box.com/s/a0ogsi5ct65rg5x4o4smsrnlblbikicp) (code for node-7.5)
and then just run *npm install* and *npm run build*.

Main files: server.js, schema.js, models/user.js and resolvers/user.js.

models/user.js

```
const typeDefinitions = `
type User {
    id: String!
    name: String
    type: Int
    isActive: Boolean
    clients: [String]
}
    schema {
    query: User
}
`;
export default [typeDefinitions]
```

resolvers/user.js:-

```
const resolverMap = {
   User: {},
};
export default resolverMap
```

schema.js

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import resolver from '../resolvers/user'
import User from './user';

export default makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: User,
    resolvers: resolver,
});
```

server.js:-

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import routes from './app/routers/index';
import { graphqlExpress } from 'graphql-server-express';
import schema from './app/models/schema'

var app = express(); // create our app w/ express

var database = require('./app/configs/database');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8888; // set the port

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json


app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
    graphiql: true,
    pretty: true,
    schema: schema
}));

app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port : " + port);
```

Comment: what error are you getting, can you please mention

Comment: It's saying "Get query missing.". And there is no graphiQl UI. Simple blank page with one message.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { graphiqlExpress } from 'graphql-server-express';
app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
  endpointURL: '/graphql',
}));
```

You need to use above code,

`graphiql: true` is not supported anymore I guess,
You need to import a graphiql method and pass an endpoint for the same