# GET query missing: Implementing GraphQL Using Apollo On an Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm following the tutorial here: [Implementing GraphQL Using Apollo On an Express Server](https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-graphql-using-apollo-on-an-express-server) and I'm getting the error **GET query missing** in the browser at http://localhost:7700/graphql.

First I typed all the code myself. When I encountered the error, I downloaded the code from [GitHub: kimobrian/GraphQL-Express: An Express Server implemented using GraphQL](https://github.com/kimobrian/GraphQL-Express) to eliminate the possibility that I had made a mistake. However, I'm still getting the same error.

I presume it is better to provide the link to the repo rather than paste the code here because I'm using the same code from the repo. Also, I am not sure which file might contain the problem.

```
$ npm start

> tutorial-server@1.0.0 start kimobrian/GraphQL-Express.git
> nodemon ./server.js --exec babel-node -e js

[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node ./server.js`
GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:7700
```

The error is **GET query missing** in the browser at http://localhost:7700/graphql. It's the same in Firefox and Chromium.

Update: The only question I find with relevant information is here: [nodejs with Graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377255/nodejs-with-graphql). The suggested solution is

```
server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
  endpointURL: '/graphql',
}));
```

However, that's exactly the code I have already (from the tutorial). Here is my entire `server.js`:

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

import {
    graphqlExpress,
    graphiqlExpress,
} from 'graphql-server-express';

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { schema } from './src/schema';

const PORT = 7700;
const server = express();
server.use('*', cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:7800' }));

server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
    schema
}));

server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql'
}));

server.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

Comment: Check your package version. Its seems your package name changed to require('apollo-server-express') https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-server-express. Use this one to integrate GraphQL on Express https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the API and the package name itself have changed since that tutorial was written (the package is now `apollo-server-express`). You no longer need to import `cors` or `body-parser`. The simplest way to get started is to actually just use apollo-server:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const port = 7700;

server.listen({ port });
```

If you still want to apply other middleware yourself, you can use `apollo-server-express`:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const port = 7700;

app.listen({ port });
```

Please check [the official docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started.html) for more details.

Comment: I am getting same issue with fastify. I have followed the steps from - https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-fastify. On hitting http://localhost:3000/graphql it is giving me 'Get Query missing'. Please help

Comment: @khushboo29 Please open a new question with all relevant code.

Comment: Yeah, I opened one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072227/apollo-graphql-with-fastify

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by addding two fields into Apollo Server constructor: `playground: true` and `introspection: true`:

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: (ctx: Context) => ctx,
  playground: true,
  introspection: true,
});
```

**Note:** Beware that cors should be set up properly for your graphql server to be able to answer requests.

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63875344/7735423).

Comment: I searched everywhere, but only the ```playground: true``` parameter helped