# Apollo Graphql with Fastify

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, fastify

I have been trying to run Apollo Ghraphql server with Fastify. Code snippet for index file below:-

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-fastify');
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
const config = require('./config')

const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('./schema');
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
    resolvers
});

fastify.register(server.createHandler());
(async function () {
  await fastify.listen(config.port, config.host, (err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
      process.exit(1)
    } else {
      console.log(`API server listening on port ${config.port} and host ${config.host}`)
    }

  })
})();
```

And my schema is like

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
        items: [Item!]!
        item: Item,
        hello: String!
    }
    type Item {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        message: String!
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello: () => "Hello World",
        items: () => {
      return {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test',
        message: 'test111'
      }
    },
    }
};

module.exports = {
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
};
```

When I start the server and try to access http://localhost:3000/graphql I am getting message "GET query missing." on the screen.

I am referring this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-fastify. Am I missing any step. Please help.

Comment: Which version of fastify are you using?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon, "apollo-server-fastify": "^2.16.0", "fastify": "^3.1.1",

Comment: I'm not sure apollo has upgraded to fastify 3, try to install fastify v2

Comment: Yes. Issue is with version only. When I downgraded to "fastify": "^2.10.0". It started working fine. Thanks @ManuelSpigolon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now fastify v3 has been released few weeks ago and not all the ecosystem has been upgraded as well.

So you need to install fastify v2 `npm i fastify@2` since right now the latest is v3.